# iPad - can't detect orientation

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad, orientation

I am trying to lay out some subviews in viewDidLoad by taking into account the orientation,
Here's my code. The NSLog is never executed. Please help.

```
-(void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


    if ( UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation)) {

    }

    if ( UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation)) {

        NSLog(@"This is landscape");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that's because a view is always loaded in portrait.

**EDIT:** Try:

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    // Your code...
}
```

Comment: Views are always loaded in portrait mode, and then immediately experience a rotation if the device is in landscape.

Comment: That is if he hasn't specified the initial orientation as Landscape.

Comment: +1 `viewDidLoad` is definitely not the right place to set up your layouts.